# is it possible to sign multiple embedded singers in single recipient view?

Tags: docusignapi

I went through lot of stack overflow questions, but still have some questions:

- is it possible to make it sign two signers in single recipient view in embedded signing?
- which signer will get chance to sign if routing order is not given in embedded signing in this scenario?
- is it based on which recipient view we are creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re:

- is it possible to make it sign two signers in single recipient view in embedded signing?

Not really. Much much better is to have a different embedded signing ceremony per signer. That way you can maintain all of the authentication data per signer. Remember that you need the ability to enforce non-reputability (not allow someone who signed to claim that they didn't sign) if there is a dispute.

- which signer will get chance to sign if routing order is not given in embedded signing in this scenario?

When you create an embedded signing ceremony, you specify who the signer is. You tell DocuSign the signer's email, name, and clientUserId to identify the signer to DocuSign. In return, you receive the URL for that signer for that envelope.

- is it based on which recipient view we are creating?

Yes, the Recipient View is the signing ceremony if the specified recipient has not signed yet. If the specified recipient is not a signer or is a signer who already signed, then they see the appropriate view of the envelope and its documents.

Remember that with embedded signing, you need to already know who the signer is by authenticating him or her. Or you can tell DocuSign to authenticate the signer. But in any case, you need to authenticate *each* signer.

Otherwise you will have no way to later prove that the signature wasn't a forgery (Alice signed, pretending to be Samantha) or to enforce non-reputability (prove that it must have been Ben who signed even though he claims that he didn't sign.)